# My Script Stops Executing after I upload my zip file to Azure

Tags: azure, powershell

Currently I am working on a script that gets a bunch of information and then puts it into a folder and zips it up. Then I upload it to an Azure blob container. After I upload it, I want to delete the zip file from the local computer however it does not get deleted as the script stalls after upload the zip file to Azure.

```
$fileName = Split-Path -Path $destinationPath -Leaf

$storageAccountName = "accname"
$storageContainerName = "containername"
$resourceGroupName = "resourcename"

$GetStorageAccountContext = Get-AzStorageAccount -Name $storageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
$storageContext = $GetStorageAccountContext.Context

Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Context $storageContext -Container $storageContainerName -File $destinationPath -Blob $fileName -Force

Remove-Item $destinationPath -Recurse -Force
```

`$destinationPath` is the location of my zip file.
The script does upload the information to Azure, but it gets stuck after that.
It does not seem to be a problem with the Zip file, as I tried just doing Remove-Item on a random folder, but the script was still stalled at Set-AzStorageBlobContent.

Comment: I'm guessing that you're trying to delete the file before it's done being uploaded. Try adding a `Do{Start-Sleep -Sec 1}Until((Get-AzStorageBlobCopyState -Blob $fileName -Container $storageContainerName).status -ge 2)` before you delete. 2 is  success, 3 is aborted, 4 is failed. You could build logic around that for if you delete the local file or not.

Comment: The file is not getting release by PS so you can't delete : $GetStorageAccountContext.Dispose(); $storageContext.Dispose();

Comment: @jdweng are you saying to call $GetStorageAccountContext.Dispose(); $storageContext.Dispose(); after I do Set-AzStorageBlobContent?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I tried that out by putting that statement after my Set-AzStorageBlobContent, but it still does not reach to that point as it is still stalled at the Set cmd

Comment: Okay I got it to work, I did  I added -AsJob to the Set-AzStorageBlobContent Cmd and then did
        Wait-Job $(Get-Job);
        Remove-Job $(Get-Job); if anyone sees any problems with this please mention it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to upload multiple files to Azure blob using the below PowerShell using `As-Job`, and it got uploaded successfully.

```
    $destinationPath = "C:\folder"

    $fileName = Split-Path -Path $destinationPath -Leaf
    
    $storageAccountConnectionString = "BlobEndpoint=https://testctsbe87.blob.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://storageaccountname.queue.core.windows.net/;FileEndpoint=https://testctsbe87.file.core.windows.net/;TableEndpoint=https://testctsbe87.table.core.windows.net/;SASToken"
    $containerName = "venkatcontainer"
    $storageAccountName ="testctsbe87"
    $resourceGroupName ="Test-CTS"
    $GetStorageAccountContext = Get-AzStorageAccount -Name $storageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
    $storageContext = $GetStorageAccountContext.Context
    Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Context $storageContext -Container $containerName -AsJob
Remove-Item $destinationPath  -Recurse -Force
```

**Output**

[image]

Once ran the above code files are uploaded successfully to **Azure blob** and the local folder is also deleted.

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the `Azcopy copy` command to copy the files to Azure blob.

```
   azcopy copy "/home/xxxxx/ZipFolder.7z" "https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/SASTOKEN" --recursives
   $destinationPath = "/home/xxxxxxxx/ZipFolder.7z"                
 Remove-Item $destinationPath -Force
```

**Output:**

[image]